# IE Flexbox justify-content center overflow issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

When viewing the following demo on IE11, there is an issue in which the content is displayed aligned right and pushed outside of the screen.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/aaronvanston/pen/ORXLdy)

Here is the code that justifies the content center:

```
.search-results {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}
```

You can see the issue in this screenshot here: [image]

I'm using [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/) IE 11 on windows 10 to emulate.

It seems to be calculating the width of the flex wrapper greater than it actually is. No amount of setting max-/width on the element, HTML or body seems to fix it. I understand IE11 has some flaky support for flexbox, is there a property I'm missing? Vendor prefixes are being added by Codepen, so I should be covered on that basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flex-basis should be set to avoid these problems in IE. Change the flex property of the ".search-results__list" to `flex: 0 1 712px`. Check the example below:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKKpGx

> IE 10-11 don’t allow unitless flex-basis values in the flex shorthand.

For more info: https://philipwalton.com/articles/normalizing-cross-browser-flexbox-bugs/

Comment: Thanks @cewn! I remember IE needed flex-basis, however forgot to implement in this project. This is exactly what fixed it! Appreciate the help :)